# If one of the column value match with another array return the dataframe of unique id with all of it's rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
 df=
    id - val1
    1  -  50
    2  -  40
    1  -  60
    2  -  41

a = [50]

output = id - val1
         1  -  50
         1  -  60
```

Suppose i have a panda dataframe like df and a array like 'a'. Now if any of the value of val1 column of df column match with this array i want to return all the entry of unique id (like output). How can i do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
df[df.groupby('id')['val1'].transform(lambda x: x.isin(a).any())]
```

or alternatively, nested `isin`:

```
df.loc[df['id'].isin(df.loc[df['val1'].isin(a), 'id'])]
```

[out]

```
   id  val1
0   1    50
2   1    60
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use groupby's [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) and [any](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html#pandas.DataFrame.any) to get the unique ids that match a:

```
 a = [50]

 df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: x.val1.isin(a).any())

    id  val1
0   1   50
2   1   60
```